# How to implement SPA "the right way"

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, search-engine, dom-manipulation

Okay, Single Page Applications in combination with a Progressive Web App approach is the new orange (or is it still black? I have a hard time keeping up with the lingo).

You basically use web workers (or not, it's not important) to fetch data from (for example) an API, and then on the fly generate the HTML you need to present the data in your app.

```
// just a really quick and dirty example
fetch('http://example.com/pages/welcome')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const heading = document.createElement('h1');
        const headingText = document.createTextNode(data.title);
        heading.appendChild(headingText);
        document.querySelector('#content').appendChild(heading);
    });
```

The problem is that when you take this approach your DOM and content is basically invisible to search engines and other types of crawlers because these usually ignore any javascript post-rendering and DOM manipulation.

I've noticed a lot of people in tutorials about this approach claim that single page applications can have great impact on your SEO, *unless implemented correctly*.

And here's the question, because none of the tutorials I've read or seen go on to explain how this correct implementation then is done.

I know about prerenders such as [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/), but is that really the only solution to make a single page application readable to crawlers and search engines? What is this magical "correct" way of implementing a single page application?

Comment: As of 3 years ago (2015) you no longer need to do anything special to get google to crawl SPA. Google no longer looks at HTML when crawling. Instead Google now creates a DOM just like a browser and then crawl that DOM. Here's the announcement from Google: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: This has been discussed in other places as well: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85200/will-google-bing-crawl-my-website-both-with-and-without-javascript-or-with-only

Comment: Here's Google's own guide on how to make sure your website is crawlable by Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en

Comment: Here's Google's official tool to check how google sees your site: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?visit_id=1-636559211436168775-519524055&rd=2

Comment: @slebetman That's great! Thanks for the links. But that's just google. What about when you link to a page in a social media app like facebook or twitter. The generated card in that social media is not rendered correctly still.

Comment: Maybe use `<noscript>` to generate the output you want them to show.

Comment: @Barmar I could do that, sure. But then I will have to generate the HTML twice; once on the server to place in a noscript tag, and second in the browser to render it in the async spa. I think this goes against one of the major advantages of using the browser to render your DOM.